# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.0.0' after upgrading to 1.1.0

Tags: dll, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Asp.Net Core project targeting .NET 462 and it was working with Asp.Net Core version 1.0.1. After upgrading to "1.1.0" I got this error:

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting": "1.2.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.1.1",
    "AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection": "1.1.2",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "JetBrains.Annotations": "10.2.1",
    "libphonenumber-csharp": "7.7.4",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "MotleyFlash": "0.3.0",
    "MotleyFlash.AspNetCore.MessageProviders": "0.2.0",
    "MotleyFlash.AspNetCore.ViewHelpers": "0.2.0",
    "SendGrid.NetCore": "1.0.0-rtm-00002",
    "System.Interactive.Async": "3.1.0",
    "Twilio": "4.7.2"
},
"frameworks": {
    "net462": {
        "dependencies": {
            "TaxiGun.Server.IdentityServer.Data": {
                "target": "project"
            },
            "TaxiGun.Server.Services": {
                "target": "project"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

When I take a look at on build output folder, I can see all the libraries in a proper version except "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer":
[image: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer]

I think it is causing the problem. But I just can not figure out why the version is wrong? Is it because the nuget package has a wrong version inside?

Comment: I have deleted local Nuget repository and now I get this error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Admin\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer\1.0.1\lib\net451\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll'. I do not reference 1.0.1 version anywhere. Strange.

Comment: Try deleting your `project.lock.json` file and restore the packages again

Comment: Yes, I tried, it did not help. What actually helped is strange: I jhave created a  new AspNET Core project, referenced my other project, update to the latest libraries and then removed the new project and he we go, the "old" project is now working too.

Comment: I see the problem in your `project.json` now. When updating libraries using NuGet manager, all dependencies are moved to the `dependencies` section, even the ones that weren't and shouldn't like the `tools` (eg: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools` or `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`)

Comment: In other projects I have Tools in Dependencies and it works: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final", "type": "build" }.

Comment: Maybe because they are 1.0.0 projects. I'm telling you, move all your `Tools` packages to the `tools` section

Comment: Does adding a dependency on `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0"` make a difference?

Comment: @bricelam No, I don't have this package included. What helped: deleting all the bin/obj folders + lock files + computer nuget cache + dotnet restore & build. DLL HELL strikes back

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Complete project references clean-up solved my problem.

1. Delete all bin/obj folders
2. Delete all project.lock.json files
3. Delete local Nuget repository cache (computer one)
4. Remove all references from project.json file and add only required ones (with the help of R#)
5. nuget udpate, dotnet restore = project is running

When I'm thinking about it again, maybe only point 4 was important?

Comment: 1st point: deleting bin & obj folder then compile again worked for me

Comment: Regarding #4, in VS 2017, you can go into your project's .csproj file (project.json was for VS 2015).

Comment: After multiple tries I eventually did all the steps, in all orders. I eventually had luck specifically adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.` **XYZ** specific libraries the project was complaining about missing. Definitely a versioning or API dependency tree issue.

Comment: Deleting "bin" and "obj" folders and building the project solved my problem. thank u

Answer (score -2):

updated Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql in .csproj file to the latest version 3.1.1 to fix issue.