# What else can I do when the project "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" except manually empty the bin and obj

Tags: c#, .net, azure, entity-framework, azure-functions

I get this on run-time: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

I have tried the following steps by Skorunka František without success: [Link to StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704774/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserver-versio)

This is how my startup.cs file looks in my project. Its basicly from MSDN docs: [Link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services)

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(HiQFoodCourt.Functions.StartUp))]

namespace HiQFoodCourt.Functions
{
    public class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
            
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
              options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, connectionString));

            var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            });

            IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
        }
    }
}
```

I am clueless on how to troubleshoot and proceed this problem.
Here is a visual on how it looks on Visual studio:
[image: Visual on Visual studio]

I have tried the following steps by Skorunka František without success: [Link to StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704774/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserver-versio)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510301/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-logging-abstractions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue previously and the solutions I found

1. Uninstall the package
2. delete obj and bin files
3. re-install it again from nuget package

still doesn't work then

1. Delete obj and bin files
2. Add => references => browse => add the proper dll from C:\Program Files\dotnet\
3. rebuild

Hope this helps you!